# Entity framework - insert multiple with increment

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to save multiple objects to database with increment number (MAX + 1).
When I save only one object, it works correct, but when I saved multiple, all object had the same number. Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
  _context.Add(new Data(){Number = _context.Max(d => d.Number) + 1});
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How to save multiple objects to database with difference Number? Thanks

Comment: The code you show should just work. It will display the described behavior if you move the `SaveChanges()` call outside of the loop. Is that actually the case?

Comment: Why don't you use a auto-increment primary key on your database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if people ask entity-framework questions without proper specifications, they mean with identifiers like `_context` a `DbContext` object. However, a `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` doesn't have an `Add` function. So I'm not sure about what your `_context` object represents. Maybe next time you'll give proper specifications.

Luckily you showed us the three functions we need:

- How to get the maximum used value for Number
- How to add a new `Data` object
- How to save the changes.

The following code will do the job. It will query only once for the maximum number and it will save the changes only once. Hence it is more efficient than your solution.

```
// get the current maximum number:
var maxNumber = myDbContext.MyItems.Select(myItem => myItem.Number).Max();

// create objects with a proper value for Number:
var objectsToAdd = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)     // from numbers 1..10
    .Select(i => new Data()                    // make a new Data object
    {
         Number = maxNumber + i,               // with value of Number = maxNumber + i
     })
     .ToList();

     // add the created objects and save the changes
     foreach (Data objectToAdd in objectsToAdd)
     {
         _context.Add(objectToAdd
     }
     // Perhaps there is a _context.AddRange(...)?
     _context.SaveChanges();
```

Note that this method only works correctly if no one else in the mean time adds Data with a Number higher than `maxNumber`. But your method has also this disadvantage: between querying for your `maxNumber` and `SaveChanges` someone else might have added `Data`